# How to make parent items to be displayed in a dropdown menu?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

There is a [menu](https://speak-time.com/) created with pdoMenu. Each parent item must be present in a dropdown menu as well. For instance "О компании" must include "О компании" as the first element of a submenu. Is there a way to make it with pdoMenu?

```
 [[pdoMenu?
&parentClass=`dropdown`
&innerClass=`dropdown-menu`
&level=`2`
&parents=`0`
&startId=`0`
&lastClass=`0`
&firstClass=`0`
&tplInnerRow=`@INLINE <li [[+classnames]]"><a href="[[+link]]" [[+attributes]]>[[+menutitle]]</a>[[+wrapper]]</li>`]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.modx.pro/komponentyi/pdotools/snippetyi/pdomenu

Play with **&tplParentRow &tplParentRowHere &tplParentRowActive** chunks and you'll gain success